# html/php form gives me 500 internal server error when adding more input fields

Tags: php, html, forms, form-submit

Hi, I have a problem with my php and html form. What I am trying to do is just get a form with 7 input fields, 6 of these are input field or text area and one will be a checkbox. I have one hidden field, the first 3 boxes the hidden field the first name and message. The only problem I have is when I add a new input box it shows me the 500 error. My code is below:

```
<?php
// display form if user has not clicked submit
if (!isset($_POST["submit"]))
  {
  ?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">

  <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="can you create me an account"><br>
  Message: <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="message"></textarea><br>
  first <input type="text" name="first_name" >
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Feedback">
  </form>

<?php 
  }
else
  // the user has submitted the form
  {
  // Check if the "subject" input field is filled out
  if (isset($_POST["subject"]))
    {
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    $first = $_POST["first_name"];


    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
    $first = wordwrap($first, 70);
    // send mail
    mail("summat@gmail.com",$subject,$message,$first,"subject: $subject\n");
    echo "Thank you for sending us feedback";
```

When I add a new input box my code looks like :

```
<?php
// display form if user has not clicked submit
if (!isset($_POST["submit"]))
  {
  ?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">

   <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="can you create me an account"><br>
   Message: <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="message"></textarea><br>
   first <input type="text" name="first_name" >
   last <input type="text" name="last_name" >
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Feedback">
  </form>

<?php 
  }
else
  // the user has submitted the form
  {
  // Check if the "subject" input field is filled out
  if (isset($_POST["subject"]))
    {
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    $first = $_POST["first_name"];
    $last = $_POST["last_name"];


    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
    $first = wordwrap($first, 70);
    $last = wordwrap($last, 70);
    // send mail
    mail("summat@gmail.com",$subject,$message,$first,$last,"subject: $subject\n");
    echo "Thank you for sending us feedback";
```

Everything shows on the screen when I add them but when I press submit I get:

> 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you
>   are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

and nothing gets submitted. Is it because it times out before it send or to much data or have I just missed something very basic?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is in your server error log?

Comment: Please, turn on PHP error reporting - in php.ini, set "display_errors=on", restart your Apache server and try to figure out where the problem is or edit your question and add the PHP error message you are getting.

Comment: and post a diff, so it's easy to see the changes.

Comment: what do you mean a diff @KarolyHorvath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6 Variables will result in:
*Warning: mail() expects at most 5 parameters, 6 given in YOUR WEBSITE on LINE*

Solution example:

```
    <?php
     //var_dump($_POST);
    if (isset($_POST["subject"]))
        {
        $subject = $_POST["subject"];
        $message = $_POST["message"];
        $first = $_POST["first_name"];
        $last = $_POST["last_name"];
        $name= "$first $last";
    }
        $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
        $first = wordwrap($first, 70);
        $last = wordwrap($last, 70);
        mail("summat@gmail.com",$subject,$message,$name,"subject: $subject\n");
        echo "Thank you for sending us feedback";
      ?>
```

Answer to your reply:
Php:

```
 <?php
 //var_dump($_POST);
if (isset($_POST["subject"]))
    {
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    $first = $_POST["first_name"];
    $last = $_POST["last_name"];
    $company = $_POST["company"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $telnr = $_POST["telnr"];
    $description = $_POST["description"];
    $therest = "First name= $first" . "\r\n" . "Last name= $last" . "\r\n" . "Last name= $last" . "\r\n" . "Company= $company" . "\r\n" . "Email= $email" . "\r\n" . "Telnr= $telnr" . "\r\n" . "Description= $description";          

    //echo "$therest <br>";
    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
    $first = wordwrap($first, 70);
    $last = wordwrap($last, 70);
    mail("Your Email Address Here",$subject,$name,$therest,"subject: $subject\n");
    echo "Thank you for sending us feedback";
}
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">

   <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="can you create me an account"><br>
   Message: <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="message"></textarea><br>
   first <input type="text" name="first_name" ><br>
   last <input type="text" name="last_name" ><br>
   company <input type="text" name="company" ><br>
   email <input type="text" name="email" ><br>
   Telephone number <input type="text" name="telnr" ><br>
   Description <input type="text" name="description" ><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Feedback">
  </form>
```

Demo: [here](http://stackoverflow.vergelijkgel.nl/questions/22831227.php)
It will send the mail to the mail your entered in the form

Comment: I know this is probably a simple question what is $resthere ?
and two how would i add other fields cause what i am trying to do in the end is @user3489793

first name,
last name ,
company,
email,
telephone number,
description

Comment: $resthere was a line i forgot to delete(edited the post now). I will edit my post and add an example for the rest of your questions

Comment: thank you that would be much appreciated due to it being the first time that i have used the `mail()`

Comment: I edited my answer. Tell me if you need any more help!

Comment: this has completely worked the only thing i would like you to do is just edit your answer in the html you put `Description` it should be `description` I have changed this in my code and it is working perfectly

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that in the 2nd example you're trying to pass 6 variables to the mail() function when it accepts 5. Check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) on how you can pass additional headers.

Comment: ohhh that makes more sence how would i add the variable into the $header section would it just be like `mail("summat@gmail.com"mail, $subject, $message, $headers);");` @tliokos